# Pull down tableview for action

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, tableview

I have a tableview with multiple rows. To add a row I have a navigation bar where the right bar button can be pressed to show a popup and add another row. I will like to scroll down the tableview at the top show the popup to add another row.

I first tried doing this with a white refresh control (so the user can not see it) and just add the row with that. This worked, but I have to pull down the tableview too far down (about 1/3 of the screen size) to add another row.

Is there a way I can do this without the refresh control to add a row so I do not have to scroll down so far? I have searched around but have not found anything.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you ask correctly, the method you need is `insertRows` of `tableView`

It automatically inserts the row at top so you wouldn't have to worry about scrolling I believe. You didnt share any code but you can make that happen inside your `rightBarButtonItem` action method:

```
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

Of course you also need to update your `dataSource` if you have one.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't as clear as I thought. The right bar button item will show a popup where you can write something and then add it to the tableview. I will like to be able to scroll down the tableview (about 50 pixels down) and show the same popup. I just edited my post to be clearer.